# Why is the convariance function for a stationary gaussian process not 0?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

As the title reads, why is the convariance function for a stationary gaussian process not 0?

Isn't every realization X(t) independent of the other realizations? If not, how come?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not independent. In fact, think of two points very close in time, for example $X(t+h)$ and $X(t)$ for $h$ small. You can see that for a continuous Gaussian process the value of $X(t+h)$ will be very correlated to the one of $X(t)$. The covariance function indicates "how strong" this correlation is. For a zero-mean Gaussian process $X(t)$, the covariance 
$$
C(t, s) = E(X(t)X(s)),
$$
is therefore a measure of how strong this correlation is. This is independent of the notion of stationarity.

Comment: How is a gaussian process generated?

Comment: Depends! Imagine your mean is $\mu(t)$ and your covariance $C(t,s)$. You can compute $C(t_i, t_j)$ and $\mu(t_i)$ for a partition $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_N = T$, thus obtaining a matrix $C$ and a vector $\mu$. Then, you compute $C = LL^\top$ via Cholesky. Then you generate $Z \sim \mathcal N(0, I)$ in $\mathbb R^{N+1}$ (easy), and obtain a realization of $X(t)$ via $X = \mu + LZ$.